# Yeoman Sharepoint Client-side Solution Generator stops taking input

Tags: sharepoint, yeoman, spfx

I'm trying to install Sharepoint Client-side Solution using Yeoman but running into difficulties.

I can't get passed the 4th question, it doesn't accept any input so I can't answer it.

**Versions**

node v8.1.0

yo v2.0.0

gulp v3.9.1

microsoft/generator-sharepoint v1.3.2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what is the issue here as it looks to be specific to your machine. I am able to get past the questions and create a solution.

However, as a workaround for your issue, you can try the below steps:

Paste the below command to see the list of command line options available for the SharePoint generator

`yo @microsoft/generator-sharepoint --help`

It will show up as below:

[image]

Based on that, you can create the command string and generate the project as below:

Assume that you want to create an SPFx webpart with React framework, then your command would be as below:

```
yo @microsoft/sharepoint --solutionName "hello-world" --framework "react" --componentType "webpart" --componentName "HelloWorld" --componentDescription "HelloWorld web part" --environment "spo" skipFeatureDeployment false
```

Similarly, you can create/modify the above command as per your requirements.

Reference - [Scaffold projects using yeoman SharePoint generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/toolchain/scaffolding-projects-using-yeoman-sharepoint-generator)

Also, ensure that you have enough disk space for those node modules. It will take up approx 300 MB space.